# Can background image extend beyond div's borders?

Tags: css, image, html

Can background image extend beyond div's borders?  Does overflow: visible apply to this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, a background can't go beyond the edge of an element.

The `overflow` style controls how the element reacts when the content is larger than the specified size of the element.

However, a floating element inside the `div` can extent outside the div, and that element could have a background. The usefulness of that is limited, though, as IE7 and earlier has a bug that causes the `div` to grow instead of letting the floating element show outside it.

Answer (score 30):

Following up on [kijin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481206/kijin)'s advice, I'd like to share my solution for image offsets:

```
/** 
  * Only effective cross-browser method to offset image out of bounds of container AFAIK, 
  * is to set as background image on div and apply matching margin/padding offsets:
  */

#logo {
  margin:-50px auto 0 auto;
  padding:50px 0 0 0;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
```

I used this example on a simple div element `<div id="logo"></div>` to position my logo with a `-50px` vertical offset.  (Note that the combined margin/padding settings ensure you don't run into collapsing margin issues.)

Comment: The padding should be positive, not negative. A negative padding is invalid, so the style will be ignored.

Comment: This works well (tested with IE7, IE8, IE9, Firefox, Safari, Chrome), thank you!

Comment: I tend to notice subtle browser/device/OS inconsistencies with both negative padding and margin, so I've started to avoid it.  It works in some cases and I usually see an issue when I'm, for example, trying to inline position list items of an unordered list.

Comment: This is a great solution. Also works well with percentages. If you want to add content to a child element, you can set it to 50% (which becomes 100% of the screen).

Answer (score 11):

not possible to set a background image 'outside' it's element,

**BUT YOU CAN DO** what you want with using **'PSEUDO'** element and make that whatever size you want and position it wherever you want.
see here :
i have set the arrow outside the span
[image]

here is the code

**HTML :**

```
<div class="tooltip">
<input class="cf_inputbox required" maxlength="150" size="30" title id="text_13" name="name" type="text"><span class="msg">dasdasda</span>
</div>
```

**strong text**

```
 .tooltip{position:relative; float:left;}
    .tooltip .msg {font-size:12px;
        background-color:#fff9ea;
        border:2px #e1ca82 solid;
        border-radius:5px;
        background-position:left;
        position:absolute;
        padding:4px 5px 4px 10px;
        top:0%; left:104%;
        z-index:9000; position:absolute; max-width:250px;clear:both;
    min-width:150px;}


    .tooltip .msg:before {
        background:url(tool_tip.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    content: " ";
        display: block;
        height: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        left:-10px; top:1px;
        width: 20px;
        z-index: -1;
        }
```

see here example: http://jsfiddle.net/568Zy/11/

Answer (score 9):

No, the background won't extend beyond the borders. But you can stretch the border as far as you want using `padding` and some clever tweaking of negative margins & position.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is really really late, and I am not even sure if this is best practice but I found a little way to do this with my footer. My last section had a background image that I wanted to overflow into the footer and I fixed it with a few lines of CSS. Also added a little padding the section with the background image.

```
footer{
 background-color: transparent!important;
 top: -50px;
 margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

Comment: Ya this is great for overlapping things on the Y-axis

Answer (score 0):

I tried using negative values for `background-position` but it didn't work (in firefox at least).  There's not really any reason for it to.  Just set the background image on one of the elements higher up in the hierarchy.

Comment: Negative background position values is used for sprite images, so that actually relies on the background *not* displaying outside the element. :)

Answer (score -2):

After a little bit of research: No and No :)

Comment: Thanks- gave the answer to Guffa cuz he gave some more detail