# Image background over the lines

Tags: css, image, html, margin

I would like to obtain button links with an image over the lines.

[I did](http://jill-jenn.net/drafts/background-image-over-the-lines), actually, using CSS:

```
section a:link, section a:visited {
    width: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    background: #03c;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 60px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

section div {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.pdf div {
    background: transparent url('pdf.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}
```

Then HTML:

```
<section class="pdf">
    <div></div>
    <a href="#">Sheet music (PDF)</a>
</section>
```

But isn't there a better solution than using negative margins [that don't work in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056410/can-background-image-extend-beyond-divs-borders)? I tried to put a certain `margin-top` into `section a` tags, but due to collapsing margins, it didn't work.

(Wow, my reputation didn't allow me to embed an image nor add more than 2 external links.)

Comment: Your test case does not include http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/, which is required to make HTML5 semantic elements such as `section` work in < IE9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jill; in your code you put an image outside the link so when you hover the image then your link hide. i don't know you do it intentionally or not . may be you can use position absolute.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><span>&nbsp;</span>Sheet music (PDF)</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;    
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0033CC;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;

}
a span{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background: url("http://www.jill-jenn.net/drafts/background-image-over-the-lines/pdf.png") no-repeat ;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:-5px;
    left:10px;
}
a:hover{
    background:red;
}
```

check this example 
http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/AwkwF/
 may be that's help you

Answer (score 0):

or try something like this, where almost everything is same, but image background is on span tag

```
<a href="#"><span>Sheet music (PDF)</span></a>
```